# Noob question about inserting a link as an image

Tags: html

I was asked to take one of our banners, remove the CTA button, but still keep the text (the one marked Abso title in the code) and link alive. I think what they want is to attach the link to the image instead and so that's what I've been trying to do.. without success.

What I've tried so far is deleting the div class that contains the button and instead inserting it somewhere else but I'm lost as to the syntax I'm supposed to follow.

I know this is probably a very simple fix but I'm lost, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. The piece of code that contains the banner/CTA/text:

```
<section class="abso-top-3 hmid vmid" style="background-image: url(/media/wysiwyg/home/BoxingWeek-bottomleft-1000x400.jpg);">
  <div class="abso-action-toolbar-top" style="margin-top: 0px;/* text-align: left; font-style: italic;">
    <div class="abso-title" style=" font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 40px; font-weight: 900; text-align: left; line-height: 0.8; font-style: normal; color: black;">
        boxing day</br><span style="font-size: 40px;color: black;">accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div class="abso-action-toolbar-banner" style="text-align: left; font-size: 35px;">
        <a href="/en_ca/hockey-ice-skating/bags-accessories/hockey-accessories.html" class="action primary-alt" title="Magasiner hockey">SHOP NOW</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The only "CTA" I'm familiar with is the Chicago Transit Authority. What are you trying to remove exactly?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Call To Action

Comment: Trying to remove the button that says "Shop Now", and instead attach the link to the image itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that you don't have an *image* but a background, which means that if you want the background image to be a link you're going to have to make the whole `section` a link.

```
<a href="/en_ca/hockey-ice-skating/bags-accessories/hockey-accessories.html" class="action primary-alt" title="Magasiner hockey">
  <section class="abso-top-3 hmid vmid" style="background-image: url(/media/wysiwyg/home/BoxingWeek-bottomleft-1000x400.jpg);">
    <div class="abso-action-toolbar-top" style="margin-top: 0px;/* text-align: left; font-style: italic;">
      <div class="abso-title" style=" font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 40px; font-weight: 900; text-align: left; line-height: 0.8; font-style: normal; color: black;">
        boxing day</br><span style="font-size: 40px;color: black;">accessories</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>
```

Basically remove the `div` that has the "shop now" text and move the link (`a` tag) to wrap the section.

Comment: Yeah this is it! I knew it had something to do with this not being a normal image but couldn't quiet put my finger on it. I tried it with one of my banners and it seems to work well. Thank you!